# Array Cloning from one class to main

Tags: java, arrays, windows

What is supposed to happen here is it will bubble sort the number n (10) and then time it and print out how long it takes, however it is not recognizing the clone i think? anyone help me. dont make fun of me for asking dumb question :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 10;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        count++;

    System.out.println(count);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SortingAlgorithms.BubbleSortCS(array.clone());
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.printf("BubbleSort: %,d\n", elapsed);

}
```

here is the class

```
public class SortingAlgorithms {

public static void BubbleSortCS(int[] array) {

    for (int i=0; i <array.length - 1; i++){
        boolean Swap = false;

        for (int j=0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++)
            if(array[j] > array[j+1]){
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = temp;
                Swap = true;
            }
        if(Swap == false)
            break;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you every declaring your variable `array` in your `Project7` class? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: Why do have a tag for windows?

Comment: thank you very much @MihirKekkar

Comment: because im on windows. im new here so explain why i shouldnt do that

Comment: You'd want to tag your question with windows when it is relevant to the problem you're encountering. In this case, your problem is with the actual Java program, not the operating system you're running it on. Also, because of the way the Java programs are run through a JVM rather than directly through your operating system, some general code like what you have should retain the same core functionality whether you were to run it on a machine running Windows or one running Mac OS because both would run it through the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sorting in place (the sorting array has no return type), don't give a clone, give a reference. If you give a clone, the original array is not affected at all. The actual bubble sort algorithms looks fine.

```
SortingAlgorithms.BubbleSortCS(array); // don't pass array.clone().
```